# Effect of withdrawing money on ISA contribution allowance

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

If I haven’t put my ISA allowance in this year but have taken £12,000 out of my ISA, how much can I put in for that year?

Answer (score 8):

Either the normal annual allowance, or (the normal annual allowance plus £12,000), depending on if your ISA is 'flexible'. From [the gov.uk information page](https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts/withdrawing-your-money) (my emphasis):

> If your ISA is ‘flexible’, you can take out cash then put it back in
> during the same tax year without reducing your current year’s
> allowance. **Your provider can tell you if your ISA is flexible.**
>
> > **Example**
> >
> > Your allowance is £20,000 and you put £10,000 into an ISA
> > during the 2020 to 2021 tax year. You then take out £3,000.
> >
> > The amount you can now put in during the same tax year is:
> >
> > - £13,000 if your ISA is flexible (the remaining allowance of £10,000 plus the £3,000 you took out)
> > - £10,000 if your ISA is not flexible (just the remaining allowance)